# Selenium testing in eclipse giving error

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testcase

I am trying to run a test case in java selenium with testing in eclipse but I am getting the below error .Is there anyone who can help me.?

```
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber: 15; The content of element type "classes" must match "(class*,parameter*)".
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:325)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:90)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber: 15; The content of element type "classes" must match "(class*,parameter*)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:305)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Please share your testng xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">; <suite name="Default suite"> <test verbose="2" name="Default test"> <classes> <class name="tests.NewSellerRegistration_Test"/> <methods> <include name="test_new_seller_registration" /> <!-- <class name="tests.InterestedSeller_Test"/> <methods> <include name="test_filter_assignee" /> --> <!-- <include name="test_complete_preregistration" /> --> </methods> </classes> </test> <!-- Default test --> </suite> <!-- Default suite -->

Comment: It's because you have closed your class tag before method tag

Comment: Use this.      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"; > <suite name="Default suite"> <test verbose="2" name="Default test"> <classes> <class name="tests.NewSellerRegistration_Test"> <methods> <include name="test_new_seller_registration"/> </methods> </class></classes> </test> </suite>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of white spaces in your testng xml

Try utf-8 as your encoding in your testng xml...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
      <class name="tests.NewSellerRegistration_Test"/>
      <methods>
        <include name="test_new_seller_registration" />
    
<!--       <class name="tests.InterestedSeller_Test"/>
      <methods>
        <include name="test_filter_assignee" /> -->
<!--         <include name="test_complete_preregistration" /> -->
      </methods>

    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->

Comment: This is my xml file @sunder kandaswamy.I have removed whitespace  also but after removing then also I am getting the same error.

Comment: Please try giving a space between. encoding="UTF-8" and ?>

Comment: where I have to give space can please explain.

Comment: Use this     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">; <suite name="Default suite"> <test verbose="2" name="Default test"> <classes> <class name="tests.NewSellerRegistration_Test"/> <methods> <include name="test_new_seller_registration" /> <!-- <class name="tests.InterestedSeller_Test"/> <methods> <include name="test_filter_assignee" /> --> <!-- <include name="test_complete_preregistration" /> --> </methods> </classes> </test> <!-- Default test --> </suite> <!-- Default suite -->

Comment: Use this.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Default suite"> <test verbose="2" name="Default test"> <classes> <class name="tests.NewSellerRegistration_Test"> <methods> <include name="test_new_seller_registration"/>     </methods> </class></classes> </test>   </suite>

Comment: ----> The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ----------------------again the same issue i am facing i dont know exact meaning of this lines becauase i am new in java selenium testng famework.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"; > 
<suite name="Default suite"> 
<test verbose="2" name="Default test"> 
<classes> <class name="tests.NewSellerRegistration_Test">
 <methods> <include name="test_new_seller_registration"/> </methods>
 </class>
 </classes> 
 </test>
 </suite> 
               this is current xml file but this is giving same error

Comment: Use this.      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://http://www.testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"> <suite name="Default suite"> <test verbose="2" name="Default test"> <classes> <class name="tests.NewSellerRegistration_Test"> <methods> <include name="test_new_seller_registration"/> </methods> </class></classes> </test> </suite>

Comment: It seems stack over flow has added ; when I posted it before

Comment: Thank You So much  for help @ Sunder now its working

Comment: @yogesh if the answer helped you please mark it as solve right answer and please vote up....so it'll be helpful for community

Comment: actually this happened because i forgot to close.    <class>  Thank You for helping

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, I had the same issue. But partially followed he above solution for me. Even i had not closed the  tag. But i had closed it something like with in the tag ex:

```
 <class name="com.Grid.MobileGrid" />
```

But i tried doing it different like:

```
 <class name="com.Grid.MobileGrid">
 </class>
```

which worked, just posting this so that it can be helpful to some one in case.
Its not about white space, some times closing the tag within the line doesnot work, u have to have it as a separate tag